# Creating a new sharable text file using Flutter in Android 10 and above

Tags: flutter, android-10.0, android-11, scoped-storage

Starting from API 29 (Android 10), [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) was introduced. Earlier I was able to directly create a sharable file and write in it using this in **Flutter**:

```dart
File f = File("/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/myFile.txt");
await f.writeAsString(contents);
```

But with [privacy changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) now it seems impossible to do the same in Android 10 even after I give the Storage permission.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate_app_data),

> Move any shared non-media files to an app-dedicated subdirectory of the Downloads/ directory.

My questions are:

- Can I still create a file in `/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/myFile.txt`, if yes how?
- If not, then can I create a file in `/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyApp/myFile.txt` directly from Flutter without Platform code?
- If I need to use platform specific code, is [using file picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file) the only option for txt file?

Also I **don't** want to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` because then my app won't work for Android 11.

Comment: Last time this question was closed due to android tag without giving proper answer. So I am asking it again specifically mentioning Flutter to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just thought I would throw this in here, if this is for flutter, and you want to share a file easily, then take a look at this plugin that will do most of the heavy lifting for you. It works for both iOS & Android:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share

Comment: I want to "create" files in external storage (sharable location) so that they won't get deleted on uninstalling the app. I am not sharing them. Anyway thanks for the link!

Comment: I know, I just wanted to throw a wrench in here. I thought somebody on this thread or you, might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it does not seem this has been implemented in Flutter yet to account for the new scoped storage changes. There is an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35783

Answer (score 0):

The right solution will be to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. About the part that it won't work on android 11. That's not the case I think. Just add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `AndroidManifest` file and in `build.gradle` change `targetSdkVersion 29` whereas keeping `compileSdkVersion 30`. This should work fine.

Comment: Well, yes it will work but it's just a workaround. We need to migrate to Android 11 now, 12 will soon be out.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But right now I think this might be the best choice.